# IGNORE CASE query problems saving to a table and using Allow large results

Tags: google-bigquery

I need case insensitivity in my queries so I found `IGNORE CASE` which works superbly when used in queries that target the browser (I am talking about BQ web UI). If I choose a destination table (an absolute must for me) and select `Allow Large Results` (with unchecked `Flatten Results`) then I get a cryptic error like this:

> Error: unexpected LIMIT clause at: 2.200 - 2.206

Even though this [Official Google BigQuery issue and feature request tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=211) post seems to speak of the same issue and even though the problem seems to have been acknowledged back in Jan 2015 the solution isn't apparent.

I could potentially use a bunch of temp tables with lowercased search columns as a workaround but that sounds awfully difficult with the number of tables and columns that I have and the complex queries that I intend to run.

Any other possible workarounds? Why isn't this working yet on BQ?

Comment: Query? LOWER ()?, job id?

Comment: Job id: earnest-stock-91916:job_rDy7otrfpR6ECEdB6PCVQ0QMuNs

Comment: So if you share your query, someone might attempt to re-write it using LOWER() instead of IGNORE CASE.

Comment: I would prefer if IGNORE CASE just worked. Now that I know that it's not yet operational and that I am not doing anything wrong, I can rewrite the queries myself. As I pointed out in the question, the queries are very long and complex so posting them here would probably be inappropriate.

Comment: No problem, hopefully it will be fixed soon. Sorry for the inconveniences!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a known problem, and it has not been neglected. The code changes to fix it are (surprisingly) not trivial, but they are mostly done. Not team is carefully looking how to enable and deploy them. I cannot give you a timeline, but the fix to this problem is coming.

The only workarounds in the meantime, are to wrap all the string comparisons, string GROUP BYs and string ORDER BYs with conversion to LOWER() (or UPPER()) of operands.

Comment: moving comment to more recent submission