# A 228 row results query job writing to table with gives 0 rows when allow large results is True

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a SQL query that, when I write the results to a table without 'allow large results' set, will write 228 rows.

When I set allow large results however, the destination table will contain 0 rows. Both attempts use write disposition WRITE_TRUNCATE.

I see this both using the API and the BigQuery console.

The working no-allow-large-results job:

eagTEiR0wSMK6b5WLSL04vB9RfTUb8bhvEi1YFWjuhfaF_W0zEeLogxUYwOrhGyOheS_CyyaB1dUeafGPdyR592xMcbeEmpJ85_CO29PSbBAnmEBGHJVHWjpH5DvGyVCEjarfJ5XUQ9UmVT_FSHmkcEZktbfln9E_E1jobM65IuQv2sP4_r7eqK60aPaqxD7taEc1bpM2kS6GAtkxqFsUUOv_JXQgTn3ebCodHFKsdquhy3e1mfbu4QhqnoO5QCi

The non-working allow-large-results job:

G40HW4Z5zGTgL1NSCBBy380kY7Gu7WOU7s_zB9F8Kdrtao2gbzRLptWSSi76MC2gHCHPG0srssaGejfCIN4j1upjyh9vQnA3kPmuJcgm5ZgdYd3YwsmGzvcBXiPy9bY0x0GRhJXimHqhKiYbKz7fa3LljOb4kxNvB8wPazqeYj3xAXwbV8G2Sl3L6gmutvvYPalhd1CCtUbLfiw520_I4zKDgn7LYosyFjA0h9TwR8GQ80Scd5n8yKAsIEou7XDG

Query:

```
SELECT t1.email, MIN(t1.min_created_time), GROUP_CONCAT(t1.id)
FROM (
  SELECT email, MIN(created) as min_created_time, id
  FROM TABLE_QUERY([xxxxx], 'table_id in       ("yyyyyy_201601", "yyyyyy_201602",     "yyyyyy _201603", "yyyyyy_201604")')
WHERE created >= "2016-01-11 00:00:00" AND created < "2016-04-01    00:00:00" AND id != "null" AND name LIKE "%trike%"
  GROUP BY email, id
   ) t1

GROUP EACH BY t1.email     
IGNORE CASE
```

Also note, a simpler SQL works for both cases such as:

```
select email from xxxx group by email limit 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem due to IGNORE CASE. The fix is underway, but in the meantime could you wrap string comparisons with LOWER() calls, i.e.

```
LOWER(id) != "null"
LOWER(name) LIKE "%trike%"
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, you are probably referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441371/ignore-case-query-problems-saving-to-a-table-and-using-allow-large-results? The related Google issue dates back to 2015/1. Is there an expected fix date for this issue? In my case no error is generated.

Comment: Also, does the usage of LOWER() on all string comparisons vs IGNORE CASE incur cost in terms of performance and billing?

Comment: There is no difference in performance or billing, IGNORE CASE is just a convinience, although it is pretty fragile, since it doesn't allow query composition. The other issue you refered to is related, but not the same. I expect fix to be live within couple of weeks.